# Understanding Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, sudoku

```
def cross(A, B):
    "Cross product of elements in A and elements in B."
    return [a+b for a in A for b in B]

digits   = '123456789'
rows     = 'ABCDEFGHI'
cols     = digits
squares  = cross(rows, cols)
unitlist = ([cross(rows, c) for c in cols] +
            [cross(r, cols) for r in rows] +
            [cross(rs, cs) for rs in ('ABC','DEF','GHI') for cs in ('123','456','789')])
units = dict((s, [u for u in unitlist if s in u]) 
             for s in squares)
peers = dict((s, set(sum(units[s],[]))-set([s]))
             for s in squares)
```

Could somebody please help me understand (in simple terms) what the last two lines mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
units = dict((s, [u for u in unitlist if s in u]) 
             for s in squares)
```

is the same as

```
units = dict()
for s in squares:
    units[s] = [u for u in unitlist if s in u]
```

or even similar as the following inefficient version

```
units = dict()
for s in squares:
    units[s] = []
    for u in unitlist:
        if s in u:
            units[s].append(u)
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the first line but what about the second?

Comment: @LewisC: Read about Python [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set), and the built-in sum